# How to create an auth token in a webapp2 script?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to make testing endpoints in a Google App Engine instance easier by using a script. Based on this information https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/testing.html, I wrote a simple script like this:

```
from main import app

params = {
    'top': 'true',
    'sort_by': 'most-recent',
}

query = urllib.urlencode(params)
url = '/activities?' + query

request = webapp2.Request.blank(url)
response = request.get_response(app)
```

But there is a problem: my handler has a security check to ensure only signed-in user can call the endpoint. It will return status code of 401 (`HTTPUnauthorized`) if the cookie `__auth__` is not set propertly

```
HTTPUnauthorized: This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser does not understand how to supply the credentials required.
```

Here is the relevant webapp2 configuration

```
'webapp2_extras.sessions': {
    'cookie_name': '__session__',
    'secret_key': login.secrets.SESSION_KEY,
    'cookie_args': {
        'max_age': 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    }
},
'webapp2_extras.auth': {
    'cookie_name': '__auth__',
    # Use with 'remember' flag to make persistent cookies
    'token_max_age': 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    'user_attributes': []
},
```

I have tried to 'monkey-patch' my handler classes to bypass the check.

Here is the `get` function of my handler class `ActivitiesHandler` (it extends `webapp2.RequestHandler`)

```
def get(self):
    # Checking if user is logged in
    if self.secure and not self.logged_in:
        self.abort(401)
    # ...
```

My money patch code goes like this:

```
ActivitiesHandler.secure = False
```

However it does not take any effect. I think it is because the `app` variable, being a variable of a module scope, is already initialised along with all the handlers well before my money patch code is executed.

As an alternative, I want to programmatically create a `__auth__` for a valid `User` entity. But I cannot find relevant information regarding this.

Any pointer or sample code will be welcome.

Comment: Are you running the request handler in the development server? You can always detect the environment and in the `__init__()` method for your RequestHandler subclass, you can detect that you're not in production and set the flag?

Comment: No. I want to run it against any environment because sometimes the request handler outcome can be changed by the state of a data store  index. That's why I want to write a generic script to call the endpoints in order to verify the result. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the 401 isn't returned before your handler is even reached? Could you share more of your code?

Comment: Are you using the `login: admin` option in your `app.yaml` file?